# Redirecting to different views according to their type/role of user. Using Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I just wanna redirect different type of users in different views.

I have seen so much tutorials but it doesn't seem so applicable to what I have done so far. So I have is, a table which has Username, password and type( enum type which are admin and superAdmin), another table for each entity for their uniques attributes . I have done this kind of problem but without a laravel framework. I'm using Auth of laravel. How could I done this with a simple way. Thank You so MUCH!!

Comment: `admin` and `superAdmin` are defined by you, right?

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze yes..its in enum type

Answer (score 2):

Just this will work:

```
protected function redirectTo(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type == "SUPERADMIN"){ // Use your user type
        return '/superadminroute';
    } elseif($user->type == "ADMIN"){ // Use your user type
        return '/adminroute';
    } else{
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

Put this is `Auth\LoginController`. Make sure to remove `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`;

Answer (score 1):

If You have run command `php artisan make:auth` Then you have `LoginController.php`  in You `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` Folder. 
You Can Put Method `redirectTo` in that class Where You Can put your redirection Logic

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')){
            return '/superadminroute';
        } elseif($user->hasRole('ADMIN')){
            return '/adminroute';
        }

        // Of Course You Can Use route('routename') Helper fuction to generate Route
        return '/';
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

**This Function Runs when user log in successfully and it is time to redirect user to specified route.**

Hope This Helps You.

Comment: where could i use or trigger the redirectTo() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple as you can using Laravel Middleware. Maybe some code below can help :

First, make a new middleware `php artian make:middleware UserVerify`.

Second, write some logic code to redirect user by `User role` :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(\Auth::user()->type == 'superAdmin')
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->route('route_name');
}
```

Third, register this middleware to your project `App\Http\Kernel.php`

Finally, apply this middleware to your route you want.

Comment: can i apply this in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php that laravel-Auth gave?

Comment: You can, but I'm not recommended

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to achieve this is to do it this way. With this users sees what you assigned to them as a super admin. Have this tables:

```
userstable with ID, fullname, username, password and role attributes
roletable with ID and roleName attributes
moduletable with ID, moduleName and route attributes
assignModulestable with ID, roleID and moduleID attributes
asignRole table with ID, roleID and userID attributes

ROLE table:
ID  roleName
--------------
1       admin
2       sub admin


MODULE table:
ID  moduleName         route
------------------------------
8 | View Members       | /members
7 | Members Withdrawal | /withdrawals
6 | View Payment       | /payment


assignModules table:
ID  roleID  moduleID
--------------------
5  | 1    |    8
6  | 1    |    7
21 | 1    |    6
22 | 2    |    8
23 | 1    |    7

asignRole table:
ID  roleID  userID
-----------------
1 | 1 | 39
2 | 2 | 43
5 | 2 | 44
4 | 2 | 46

users table:
id  name    email                  password  role
--------------------------------------------------
39  Luke    lukem@gmail.com         1234      1
43  John    john@gmail.com          1234      2
44  mark    mark@gmail.com          1234      2
46  Peter   peter@gmail.com         1234      2

the above will be the table structure and the data therein. try to normalised the table with primary and foreign keys. 

create your corresponding forms for data insertion. As you can see above, we have two roles; admin and subadmin with ids 1 and 2 respectively

define your route and link name in module table as shown in module table
in your assign module table assign a role to a module using the ids
in the assign role table define the user and roles as shown in assignRole table above.
then you have your users table with role attribute defined
```

finally, in your layout.blade.php add this:

```
<li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o fa-fw"></i> Management<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">


                                    </li>
                                 @php
                                    $userModule = DB::table('assignModules')
                                    ->join('modules', 'modules.moduleID', '=', 'assignModules.moduleID')
                                    ->where('assignModules.roleID', '=', Auth::user()->role)
                                    ->whereRaw('modules.moduleID = assignModules.moduleID')
                                    ->distinct()
                                    ->select('modules.moduleName', 'modules.moduleID','modules.route')
                                    ->orderBy('modules.moduleID', 'ASC')
                                    ->get();
                                    @endphp
                              @if($userModule)
                                @foreach($userModule as $module)

                                     <li>
                                         <a href="{!! url($module->route) !!}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ $module->moduleName }}</a>
                                     </li>

                                @endforeach
                              @endif

                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                          @if( Auth::user()->role==1 )
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Technical Settings<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/assign-user') }}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Assign User</a>
                                    </li>
                                     <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/module') }}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Create Modules</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/assign-module') }}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Assign Module</a>
                                    </li>


                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                           @else



                           @endif
```